# How to take multiple arguments in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make it so my bash shellcode can take multiple files as arguments. How would I do this?

atm this shellcode checks if only one files exsist and it checks every $2 seconds...

How would I make it take more files as arguments?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while [ ! -e $1 ]
do
    sleep $2
    if [ -e $1 ]
    then
        echo "$1 was created!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: How would you make the find command loop until the file is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sleep time first, then loop over the remaining arguments.

```
time=$1
shift # Remove time from argument list
for file in "$@"
do
    while [ ! -e "$file" ]
    do
        sleep "$time"
    done
    echo "$file was created!"
done
```

You also don't need to test for the file's existence twice. When the loop ends, you know the file has been created.

If you want to put the time last, you can loop over the argument indexes, using indirect variables.

```
time=${!#} # last argument
for ((i = 1; i < $#; i++))
do
    file=${!i}
    while [ ! -e "$file" ]
    do
        sleep "$time"
    done
    echo "$file was created!"
done
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of this aswell, but what if I would want the timer at the end?

Comment: Change what you want